Firebase Flutter web - how to create command for beta and release?
Thank you firebase team for amazing automation to host flutter app on web!
It is very convenient to just run firebase deploy to get the updated code released.
But I want more :)
I want to verify my code is rendering well on both mobile and desktop browsers, before releasing it.
So, i want two commands, that would deploy to different entrypoints.
Something like this:
firebase deploy -t release --> https://myapp-release.web.app/
firebase deploy -t preview --> https://myapp-preview.web.app/
Is it possible to configure?

What do you expect the Firebase CLI/Hosting to do with this -t flag? There is just one Flutter web app, so how would the -t flag affect what Firebase does?

Thanks. Updated the question to contain this information.

Are you looking for deploy targets: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/targets?

Yes! Thank you! I need to read this and put it together and provide steps as answer here. But if you (or someone) have concrete simple steps how to enable my two commands, on top of your head, please share as answer and I will happily accept it.

Add targets to .firebaserc:
firebase target:apply hosting preview happycreekweb-preview
firebase target:apply hosting release happycreekweb

Update firebase.json:

Convert "hosting" from map to array of maps with one item.
Copy the item so that there are two
Add "target": "release", and "target": "preview", to each

See pull request for details: https://github.com/polina-c/hc/pull/8
